# Jhipster-UML taking too much time to generate jdl file

Tags: jhipster, xmi, jdl, uml-designer

So after many struggles trying to install the proper and working version of jhipster-uml through [github](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-uml).
I've created a microservice app through `jhipster` command then put a UMLDesigner class diagram file in this format `file.uml` .
now that i run the command `jhipster-uml file.uml`, I get this :

```
? Please choose between the available editors: (Press <space> to select, <a> to toggle all, <i> to invert selection)
>( ) umldesigner
 ( ) I don't see my editor.
```

I select the **umldesigner** then enter.
and since then more than 5 mins passed and no answers yet, what could possibly be the issue ?

Comment: small update : I've managed to export the UML file to genmymodel, generated an XMI file then tried to apply the same command with this XMI file, the issue remains the same, too much time and no answers yet

Comment: another update : tried this XMI file with the "I don't see my editor option" , doesnt work either.

Comment: maybe last update : I've added the argument --to-jdl in each of the commands mentionned didnt make it work either

Comment: jhipster-uml is abandoned as you know, so unless your model is very  complex (it shouldn't for a microservice), rewriting it in JDL manually would be faster. Once you have the JDL, JHipster IDE in Visual Studio Code will generate an image of UML class diagram. So I'm not sure it's worth spending time on this.